# Why are mov ds,[bx] and mov ds,[2345H] valid?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, masm

Why are we able to move a memory operand to a segment register in these ways using a `MOV` instruction in x86 assembly language?

Why are these valid?

```
Mov DS,[Bx]

Mov DS,[2345H]
```

Comment: its a machine code. MOV is machine command.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?  `MOV Sreg,r/m16` is listed in the insn set reference manual.  The machine-code encoding just uses the normal mod/rm byte to allow the source to be a register or memory operand.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to the manual.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no value for future readers.  The manual completely answers the entire question, so just RTFM.

Comment: No you dont undrestand my mean.lock  mov [bx],[si] in not valid so why mov ds,[bx] is valid???

Comment: `ds` is a register, not a memory location.  You should edit that invalid case into your question and explain why you think it's like `mov ds, [si]`.  But the answer is still "because `mov ds, [bx]` is encodable, but there's no way to encode `mov [bx],[si]` in machine code."

Answer (score 2):

Because those are valid forms of the MOV instruction. The MOV instruction allows the following moves (I'm omitting moves to/from control and debug registers; see your CPU manuals for further details):

```
general-purpose register <- integer constant
memory <- integer constant

general-purpose register <- general-purpose register
memory <- general-purpose register
general-purpose register <- memory

segment register <- general-purpose register
segment register <- memory
general-purpose register <- segment register
memory <- segment register
```

The CPU does not support the following moves with the MOV instruction:

```
segment register <- segment register
segment register <- integer constant
memory <- memory
```

If you wonder why, it simplifies things in the CPU. There are fewer different instructions that the CPU needs to decode and similarly there are fewer possible operand encodings. It's likely that there are also fewer special cases to handle when an instruction can access at most one memory location. And most instructions are like that. This makes the design simpler and the CPU cheaper. There are a few instructions that can access two memory locations, but they are very specialized and their memory locations aren't very flexible (they are tied to specific registers). PUSH and POP can move data between memory and stack (stack is memory). MOVSB/MOVSW/MOVSD moves data from memory at DS:(E|R)SI to memory at ES:(E|R)DI.

Your assembler doesn't let you `MOV WORD [BX], [SI]` because it knows that the CPU can't do it, the CPU simply doesn't have such an instruction. That's all there's to know about it for you now.